# video file keeps getting out of audio/video sync

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, matroska

I have a video file that when you first start it the audio comes in earlier than a the video by a few hundred milliseconds, so I adjust the audio delay in my media player, but then after a few minutes its early again, so I bump up the delay, and this continues every few minutes or so for the duration of the video.

What is causing this? I would like to fix it, but other than the manual process of applying specific audio time shifts at various points in the video, is there any sort of blanket solution to fix it? I remember reading awhile ago that decompressing the audio stream into a raw format like PCM can help, but I've tried that and it has no effect.

The file is an MKV with x264 video and AC3 audio.

Comment: The video could be at 23.97fps and the audio is at 29fps. So skewing the time and delays and such don’t work. Where did this video file — and audio file — come from? Did you combine these files on your own?

Comment: @JakeGould The video is 23.97fps according to vlc. How can I check the framerate of the audio? Is that something I could determine with ffmpeg, eac3to, or some other software? I got the video off the internet, I did not mux it myself

Comment: Use FFprobe and just run it as `ffprobe -i movie_file.mp4`. But honestly this is not something there will be an easy solution for. I might recommend you extract the video and audio separately from the file and then mux them again with ffmpeg.

Comment: I demuxed using mkvtoolnix into an mka and an mkv with no audio. Running ffprobe on the mka showed 81052 frames, since the duration is 43:16 that equals ~31 fps for the audio? Given that I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried remuxing the 2 streams with ffmpeg but the audio is still screwed up.